# div1 hide to div2 show return to div1 timed without refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh, timed

I am working on a web based kiosk and have no idea how do it in jquery

I use 2 divs div1 is startpage div2 menu if they mouseover a image, div1 hides and div2 comes up and shows the menu. But when people dont use the menu and walk away it needs to switch back to div 1 without refreshing the whole page. also the timed switch to div1 must start when div2 is active.

```
<div 
id="start" 
style="display:none; 
  position:absolute; 
  right:0px; 
  top:0px;
  width:1680px;
  height:1050px; 
  background-image:url(start/images/overlays/start_overlay.png);
  background-color:;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index:7;
  "> start content here <br> <a 
  onmouseover="ShowContent('menu'); return true;"
  href="javascript:ShowContent('menu'); HideContent('start'); ">
  [image]</a>
  <div>

<div 
id="menu" 
style="display:none; 
  position:absolute; 
  right:0px; 
  top:0px;
  width:1680px;
  height:1050px; 
  background-image:url(start/images/overlays/menu_overlay.png);
  background-color:;
  padding: 0px;
  z-index:7;
  "> Menu Content here </div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript"><!--
function HideContent(d) {
if(d.length < 1) { return; }
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
}
function ShowContent(d) {
if(d.length < 1) { return; }
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block";
}
function ReverseContentDisplay(d) {
if(d.length < 1) { return; }
if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") 
{ document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by a Kiosk? do you have an example or some code that you already have written?

Comment: Post some code and show us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you want to show div1 by default, then show div2 when user begins interacting with page and go back to div1 after some time of user inactivity.

```
$(function(){
  var activeTime = 3000,
      activeTO;

  $(document).on("mousemove keydown scroll", function(){
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();
    clearTimeout(activeTO);
    activeTO = setTimeout(kioskIdle, activeTime);
  });

  function kioskIdle(){
    $("#div1").show();
    $("#div2").hide();
  }
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rXjMV/

Comment: Yes but i use a mouseover image to open the div2 how can i get it to work on a mouseover <a onmouseover="ShowContent('menu'); return true;" href="javascript:ShowContent('menu'); HideContent('start'); ">[image]</a>

Comment: Yes like that.. mhh i need to change a lot to my old version this works good

Comment: + 1 from me can't add 1 need level 15

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rXjMV/ i want to use your example as in the first url you gave me, i have a problem when the page refreshes it keeps showing div 2 on refresh even when there is no mousemove and after some time it returns how can i fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with my fiddle, second block hidden on reload. Here is the pure page without jsfiddle controls http://fiddle.jshell.net/rXjMV/show/light/ - do you get second block on reload?

Comment: In Chrome yes, in ie10 no, but i building it for and under chrome

Comment: In Chrome I have second block showing if I reload page with hotkey - the "keydown" event fires, this is expected and correct. Do you have this problem when you reload page with click on browser reload button?

Comment: I have it when i press F5 or browser reload button or when i let the page refresh with script every 10min

Comment: Hm, this is strange, probably I can't help, sorry.

Comment: If i use the other solution jsfiddle.net/rXjMV/1 how can i delay the <a href="#" class="kiosk-activate">activate</a> when they hover over it because i dont want the cursor stays on it and it goes in a loop

Comment: The same way as hide: set timeout on link mouseover, clear timeout on link mouseleave and go to active state on timeout.